# GitGutter ocd Alignment annoyance

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Using Sublime text 3 along with GitGutter, I cannot help but feel constantly annoyed that alignment of the deleted item isn't aligned like the addition and change icons. Multiple themes and setting changes later and the issue still shows. Though it seems to be the actual position and not an alignment bug, I cannot help it from bothering me. [GitGutter problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIBrP.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like it just change it :)

GitGutter support custom themes:

1. In Sublime Text open *Preferences > Browse Packages...*
2. Create a folder `GitGutterThemeAligned`
3. Download the default theme from [github](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/tree/master/themes/Default) and put it into that folder
4. Rename `Default.gitgutter-theme` to `Default Aligned.gitgutter-theme`
5. Edit the image files `deleted_*` with an image editor of your choice
6. Open the GitGutter settings *Preferences > Package Settings > GitGutter > Settings*
7. Change the "theme" setting to `"theme": "Default Aligned.gitgutter-theme"`
8. Restart Sublime Text